# What is the difference between data centered architecture and client server architecture?

Tags: architecture, client-server

Data centered architecture:

In this architecture, the database is centralized and accessed frequently by other clients which modify the data.

Client Server Architecture:

This architecture has one or more client computers connected to a central server (maybe a database server) over a network or internet connection.

What is the difference between these two? I am unable to understand.
In both architectures, server and clients are involved. Servers have database and clients access that database for data access. 
Please help me to understand the clear difference?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an exact answer. I'd say a good guide post is a data centered architecture is one where the clients need to know the data model and can access/manipulate it directly.

A client/server architecture, there is normally some abstraction of the data layer from clients so that the data model can change only impacting the server layer, not the client layer.

In the former anything other than an additive change to the data model is likely to cause clients problems. In the latter you (as the data model owner) have more flexibility, but you also have code the abstraction yourself